# How to use Qt's QCompleter to do a partial match anywhere?

Tags: c++, qt, qcompleter

We want to use QCompleter for searching in a list of items and everything is fine, except just one thing:

QCompleter does a search using "partial match at the beginning" instead of "partial match anywhere". IOW:

Actual: searching for '*doc*' will return '*dock*', '*doctor*' etc.

Expected: searching for '*doc*' will return '*dock*' but also '*undocked*' etc.

Comment: I just updated the solutions in the thread this one is marked as duplicate to. It simplifies the process a little and might be of use for you.